# Referencing subquery columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am very familiar with MySQL syntax but am seemingly running into some growing pains moving into a PostgreSQL environment. In MySQL you can reference columns in joined subqueries easily but I am thrown errors in PostgreSQL.

For example:

```
SELECT
  a.userID,
  b.firstname,
  c.minCounter
FROM users a
JOIN users_info b ON (a.userID = b.userID)
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
      user_id,
      COUNT(*) AS 'minCounter'
   FROM sales
   WHERE
      total_amount > 500
   GROUP BY user_id
) as c ON (b.userID = c.user_id)
```

referencing the subquery "c" and its temp column "minCounter" has no issues. In PostgreSQL however, a similar query would return the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'minCounter'"
LINE 10:   COUNT(*) AS 'minCounter'
```

### Accounting for literal versus named columns

If I switch Line 10 to state: COUNT(*) AS "minCounter"

my error simply adjusts to:

```
ERROR:  column c.mincounter does not exist
LINE 4: c.minCounter
```

---

Any suggestions as to what syntax or general naming difference there are that I'm missing?

(Note, I am not sure what version of PostgreSQL we are running because it is obfuscated by our external dev team).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with *referencing* a column but with providing the alias for a column.

`'minCounter'` is not a column alias it's character literal. If you want to quote an identifier you have to use double quotes: `"minCounter"`

See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

This works as specified and required by the SQL standard (which MySQL chose to ignore and does not really distinguish between character literals using single quotes and object identifiers using double quotes).

Once you quote an identifier using double quotes, it becomes case-sensitive. So in your outer query you also need `"minCounter"` because `minCounter` is a different name (this is again according to the SQL standard which - you guessed - is also ignored by MySQL)

To sum it up:

- no quotes: a case insensitive identifier (or keyword, or operator, ...)
- double quotes: a case **sensitive** identifier
- single quotes: a constant character value (aka "character literal")

In general I'd strongly recommend to *never* quote any identifier

Comment: tried that too. I should have mentioned in my OP- I'll update because the error is different but thrown nonetheless

Comment: @JM4: see my edit. Your identifer `"minCounter"` is not the same as the reference in the outer query named `minCounter`

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name - I'm now running into GROUP BY errors from the other joins but I can take elsewhere or figure out:     ERROR:  column "c.mincounter" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 4: q.minCounter

Comment: @JM4: and again you fall into a trap with MySQL ignoring the SQL standard and implementing group by incorrectly: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: Sounds like I need to relearn proper SQL and tell MySQL to go bite a nut.

Comment: @JM4: do read the manual. The link I include contains all that information regarding identifiers and so on.